# Should I install drivers from my motherboard manufacturer or from the producers of the individual products (Intel, Nvidia, Realtek, etc...)?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, motherboard, updates

Is there a risk in installing driver updates not provided by the manufacturer of the MOBO? Will it decrease system stability or the compatibility of certain components? The drivers ASUS has on their Drivers page are out of date compared to ones provided by Intel, Realtek, etc... Is is okay to just install the ones provided by Intel, Realtek, etc...

Comment: They are the same driver basically.  The only difference is the OEMs might test a specific version on specific hardware before releasing it.  If a device works then why are you updating the driver outside of a display driver, which only makes sense, because how Nvidia and AMD provide specific performance improvements over time.  Yes;  Its perfectly fine.  Its the preferred way to install drivers, do not use "driver finding programs" those can be harmful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, it's too opinion based. Personally I almost never go to my laptop/motherboard manufacturer website unless I can't find a suitable working driver from the device manufacturer, as they're usually horribly out of date. There's no wrong or right answer really.

Comment: @Jonno You think this question is opinion based because you have ignored Murphy's Law, a principal that is almost as universally applicable as the law of gravity and perhaps even more universally applicable than the law of gravity if you include gravitational phenomena that may exist outside of the event horizon of contemporary physics.

Comment: @karel Uh.. Something like that. Murphys Law is why I'd suggest getting the latest drivers. Devices, OS's, everything updates around your drivers. Remember in 2013 when devices would randomly blue screen with an outdated WiFi driver after a windows update? [link](http://www.erichstauffer.com/technology/intel-wireless-cards-blue-screening-after-windows-update) Or when WPA was released mainstream, and the Intel 2200 b/g, a very popular card at the time, bluescreened because of it? [link](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Intel+2200+bg+blue+screen+wpa)

Comment: @Jonno: You've obviously never dealt with ATI video drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safest to stick with whatever software came with the motherboard and that includes the firmware (i.e. BIOS or UEFI). The drivers that came with the motherboard have to work with that motherboard, but by the principal of [Murphy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law) the same thing cannot be said if you just install more up-to-date drivers provided by Intel, Realtek, etc. It is wrong to assume that an updated version of software will automatically be backwards compatible with hardware that was manufactured before the updated version of the software was released. 
I would update the drivers that came with the motherboard only when directly threatened by some malfunction (e.g. Windows blue screen) if I didn't update them, never as a matter of policy or to obtain possible performance improvements.

Comment: I see, that's what I've been thinking, but I get blue screens when playing a game sometimes and was told to update my drivers. I'll try just updating to the latest drivers provided by my MOBO manufacturer (mostly from 2012) and then if that doesn't work I'll try the drivers from Intel, Realtek, etc... I can probably rollback if something goes wrong and I'll do a backup beforehand just in case.